# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJS. I am receiving error while running the Node Server. I am running Node from server.js and calling a function which is present in status.js .

server.js :-

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const getHttpsRequests = require("./status");


const app = express();
const server = new http.Server(app);
let interval;

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});


server.on('listening', () => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        getHttpsRequests(); // call the function getHttpsRequests from status.js
    }, 1000);
});
```

status.js :-

```
var https = require('https');

module.exports = function getHttpsRequests (https) {

    https.get('google.com', function (res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

       res.on('data', function (d) {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

I have installed the required packages :-

```
npm install express body-parser http --save
```

I am running the node server like,

```
node server.js
```

It is giving me error :-

```
https.get('google.com', function (res) {
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are expecting https argument in `getHttpsRequest`, but you don't pass that to the function and hence its gives you undefined inside the function even though you have exported it externally. Either you remove that argument or name it differently

```
var https = require('https');

module.exports = function getHttpsRequests (http) {

    https.get('google.com', function (res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

       res.on('data', function (d) {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: @RaviMariya its not a typo, as he has said in answer that he has named the argument differently

Comment: oh i see my bad :D

Answer (score 0):

In your `getHttpsRequests`, you're passing `https` argument which will override the parent `https`. Remove `https` argument from your function,

```
module.exports = function getHttpsRequests (){

    https.get('google.com', function (res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

       res.on('data', function (d) {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```